# Return a variable from jquery and use in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp file that contains a jquery function that listens to the onchange event of a dropdown element.

```
..
    <select id="pick">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    ....

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#pick').on('change', function() {
    var isClicked=false;
    if($(this).val()==2){
     isClicked=true;
    }
   });
   }
 </script>
```

Now, this script is in a jsp code. The problem is I want to use the boolean isClicked when the function is out of scope. I learnt I have to set a variable to read off the state of the boolean in the jquery dom . I don't know how to do this and also, I don't know how to finally use the variable set in the dom in my jsp code. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to access the variable with another JS function ? In which case you need to move the scoping of the isClicked variable outside your event function. 

If you talking about it interacting with Java code in your JSP you can't, you can only interact with it in JS or use an AJAX call or a form to submit it to a Java servlet.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do in the page when this changes?

Comment: I just want to check the sate of the variable in my jsp file when the function is out of scope and then do something else based on what the state of the variable is but not in another js function. Someone mentioned doing sth like this :  //in the js function return isClicked and get the isClicked variable from the jquery dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't just seamlessly use client-side and server-side code interchangeably. You would have to send the stored values over the network via an AJAX request.

Comment: please, how could the code be modified to send it through AJAX request?